XJC not generate correctly mixed elements
I have a application tha need genarate a xml file and send to another app.
Part of DTD of this XML is:
<!ELEMENT Description ( #PCDATA | ShortName )* > <!-- mixed: string and ShortName -->

and Element ShortName was defined:
<!ELEMENT ShortName (#PCDATA)> <!-- string -->

xjc maven plugin are generating Description class as pear the code bellow
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Description")
public class Description {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "xml:lang", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String xmlLang;

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
}

And ShorName Class
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"value"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ShortName")
public class ShortName {
// ...
}

Dont has a mixed attribute <ShortName> with accessors
I need final XML:
<Description xml:lang="pt_BR">
    a large ball made of leather or plastic and filled with air, used 
    in games of soccer<ShortName>Soccer ball</ShortName>
</Description>

Somebody has the same problemas yet?
I´m using java jdk 1.8 and xjc 2.3.1
Tanks
